# tr a A < /etc/hosts | sort -r |pr -d > /etc/hosts

Tags: shell, io-redirection, tr

In this line:

```
tr a A < /etc/hosts | sort -r |pr -d > /etc/hosts
```

what would be the expected outcome? I know lowercase 'a' would change to uppercase 'A' but what's next? Would the original file be overwritten since the redirect is to the same file name?

Comment: You should get a `bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied` error (assuming your shell is bash), unless you're running this as `root`.  `/etc/hosts` is normally writable by root only.  Iff you're running this as `root` (which you really shouldn't), you'd get an empty `/etc/hosts` as Michael Homer explained.

Answer (score 17):

The expected outcome is a blank `/etc/hosts` file.

The redirection `> /etc/hosts` occurs and [truncates the file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07) [before the programs start running](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) and `tr` begins to read from the file.

To write the output into `/etc/hosts`, you could either work with a copy of the file (or move your output file into place afterwards), or use the [`sponge` command from moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), which will soak up standard input and write to a file:

```
tr a A < /etc/hosts | sort -r | pr -d | sponge /etc/hosts
```

In that case, each "a" in `/etc/hosts` will be [replaced](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) with "A", all lines will be [sorted in reverse according to your locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html), [a blank line will be inserted between each line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html), and the result will be put into `/etc/hosts`.

---

You may also find useful:

- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)
- [Do redirection operators always open file descriptors in parallel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79036/do-redirection-operators-always-open-file-descriptors-in-parallel)

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying what I should expect with the way it was written and how to could be written to gain the expected outcome.

Comment: [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is a really great tool-suite