# For loop to iterate over directory tree extracting results from files of the same name

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, grep, for

I have a series of directories, all with `list.txt` in the same format, and I wish to put the results into a single file. I am looking to write a script that will iteratively move through each directory tree, extract a specific column from the `list.txt` file without surrounding text using the grep/awk pipeline below and write the outputs of each to the same file.

```
    grep 'bar[0-9]' file.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

I have attempted the following but I am not sure exactly where my loops in the script are going wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
##Extract ligands from toplist and concatenate to file
for i in /home/ubuntu/Project/working/library_*/Results/list.txt
do
    grep 'bar[0-9]' i | awk '{print $1}' | cat ../output.txt i
done
```

The directory tree is as follows:

```
.
├── library_1-200
│   ├── Results
│   │   ├── complex
│   │   ├── sorted.txt
│   │   └── list.txt
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── output
│   │   └── txt
│   └── summary.txt
├── library_201-400
│   ├── Results
│   │   ├── complex
│   │   ├── sorted.txt
│   │   └── list.txt
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── output
│   │   └── txt
│   └── summary.txt
├── library_401-600
│   ├── Results
│   │   ├── complex
│   │   ├── sorted.txt
│   │   └── list.txt
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── output
│   │   └── txt
│   └── summary.txt
└── library_601-800
    ├── Results
    │   ├── complex
    │   ├── sorted.txt
    │   └── list.txt
    ├── files
    │   ├── output
    │   └── txt
    └── summary.txt
```

Sample of `list.txt`, where I just want the `Name` values put into `output.txt`

```
Name    Score
bar65    -7.8 
bar74    -7.5 
bar14    -7.5 
bar43    -7.4 
bar94    -7.4 
bar16    -7.4 
bar12    -7.3 
bar25    -7.3 
bar65    -7.3 
bar76    -7.3 
bar24    -7.3 
bar13    -7.3 
bar58    -7.2 
bar68    -7.2 
bar28    -7.2
```

Solution was to put "$i" where I previously had just i and to modify to `| cat >> ../output.txt`

Comment: Assuming you mean to do something like `grep 'bar[0-9]' "$i" | awk '{print $1}' | cat > "$i"`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425801/70524

Comment: Thanks @muru. That did the job of writing to an output file, however it printed the entirety of the list.txt files to the single output, seemingly ignoring the grep and awk commands.

Comment: You probably meant `... | cat > ../output.txt`, or without the unnecessary `cat`, just ` > ../output.txt`.

Comment: Yeah now tried removing the "$i" at the end, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `i`, instead of this use `$i` in grep command.

And you said that you want to put all of them into single file then the last command should be:

```
cat >> /home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt
```

Or just:

```
>> /home/ubuntu/Project/working/output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip, it is now actually running and spitting something out, however it tells me that output.txt does not exist. is there a command I should be using instead of cat in order to create the output and add to it? It is also just printing the entirety of each list.txt and not the specific sections column I am after. Does that have to do with the way I have written the `for i in /*/list.txt`?

Comment: Please edit question and  provide a sample example of your files. And also first manually create output.txt then it will work.

Comment: Added a sample of list.txt, and the comment by @muru taught me about redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from correcting some small typos in your original code (using `"$i"` in place of `i` and redirecting the output to the output file rather than trying to output its contents), if you don't have many thousands of these `list.txt` files:

```
awk '/^bar[0-9]/ { print $1 }' /home/ubuntu/Project/working/library_*/Results/list.txt >output.txt
```

This is using `awk` to extract the first column of all lines that start with the string `bar` followed by a digit.  It does this for all files matching the patten `/home/ubuntu/Project/working/library_*/Results/list.txt`.  The extracted data is redirected to `output.txt`.

The loop becomes necessary when the filename globbing pattern `/home/ubuntu/Project/working/library_*/Results/list.txt` expands to too many names:

```
for pathname in /home/ubuntu/Project/working/library_*/Results/list.txt; do
    awk '/^bar/ { print $1 }' "$pathname"
done >output.txt
```

Note that it's more efficient to redirect the output of *the loop* than of each individual `awk` call.  Also note that `awk` easily does the job of `grep` to detect the wanted lines and that `cat` is not needed.

If you need the first column from all lines except the first (as in your example data), you can change the condition in the `awk` code from `/^bar[0-9]/` to `FNR > 1`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply. Super useful to learn and will definitely be using it in the future. I'm still finding my way around bash. How many times for the expansion would you allow before putting it into a loop?

Comment: @proteinmodels You would get an error saying `Argument list too long` if the expansion became too long. "Too long" means literally that the expanded string consisting of all matching pathnames becomes too long, so it depends on the length of the path that you expand in combination with the number of `library_*` directories that you have. I would expect it to cope with a few thousands of your directories though, more if you use _just_ `library_*/Results/list.txt` from within the `/home/ubuntu/Project/working` directory (because the pathnames would be shorter).